# Is there a driver for HP 3D Drive Guard?

Tags: drivers, hp, drive

In some HP Laptops have 3d drive guard system . i dont how it works but [there is a link about it](http://www.hp.com/sbso/solutions/pc_expertise/professional_innovations/hp-3d-drive-guard.pdf). In windows hp depends it but i didnt find a driver about it for linux .

HP 3D DriveGuard protects the hard drive (HDD) by "parking the heads" if the notebook is accidentally dropped or is abruptly impacted by another object.

Is there a driver for this for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is and you can find it [here](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ppa) and it is named `hpfall`. It is a kernel module.

Unfortunately it has not been implemented in Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 or 12.10 and the PPA is not up to date. On the other hand, jou can just install the package for Natty and it works for Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10.

---

On the page it shows how to add a PPA (Personal Package Archive). In short add these to lines to your sources:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/ppa/ubuntu natty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/ppa/ubuntu natty main
```

From command line you can also do the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmjdebruijn/ppa
```

Update the sources with `sudo apt-get update` and Ubuntu software center will show you hpfall when you search for it.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: And how would one go about installing a package for the wrong Ubuntu version?

Comment: how can i get deb ?

Comment: one second to confitm

Comment: it dont work . ''

Comment: What -does- not work? Adding the PPA? Can not find the package in  USC? Or does it install and now you dropped your notebook to test it and it broke? You are very vague... According to the bug report I found about it not being updated it does work with 12.04 and 12.10. It seems to be nothing but a kernel module. So nothing fancy. If this is about the program not working please edit it into this question. If you got problems with adding it to your system I suggest to look on AU or google how to get that working.

Answer (score 1):

[hdapsd](https://github.com/evgeni/hdapsd) claims to support HP Driveguard as well, and I think it is more actively-developed than hpfall. There's a PPA with a later version than the official repos [here](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/hdapsd).